# How do I efficiently parse a large amount of strings?

Tags: c#, performance

I have a database of let's say, 1000 strings. Whenever a user of my program writes a sentence, it checks the database, `SELECT * WHERE trigger=sentence`, and returns the data rows. Considering it's a database, this goes very fast.

For the program, though, it would be much more convenient to just load in the entire database into a `Dictionary<string, string>` at the startup. That'll allow me to use `string.Contains(sentence)`, so a (sub-)sentence can be anywhere within a sentence, rather than the entire thing.

With just a thousand strings, that's fine. But what if the database grows larger, to say.. 100.000 strings? Even more? `foreach (var w in dictionary.Keys) if (w.Contains(command)) //etc` over that much strings, potentially a few times per second?

Is there a proper way to check such a large amount of strings?
Or am I just needlessly worrying? It seems like a lot, but computers have surprised me more often.

Comment: I would suggest changing the title of this question, as its too non-specific.

Comment: The implementation of this is what will be the factor.  I'd suggest that you do cache the information locally and deal with scale problems as they arise.

Comment: There is no clear answer to this question. It depends on the computer, what yo mean by `process` and what's the average system load is like.

Comment: If reading from disk is an unacceptable performance penalty, then use a memory storage strategy or in memory database. If this list is static then consider using both. The real question is what is the end goal.

Comment: Changed the title, though chances are I don't know what I'm asking. I want to check if -any- of the database's entries are a substring of a sentence a user writes in the program, and then return a list of corresponding strings for the program to use. It works on a small scale, I'm worried it'll go very wrong when the scale grows larger. So maybe I'm asking: "Is there a known way to efficiently compare a large amount of strings?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your willing to create dynamic sql in your code:

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE 'The sentence the user typed' like '%' + [StringColumn]+ '%'
```

This should check each string against whatever the user typed.

Comment: I want to achieve the exact opposite of what that does, though. The database contains the substrings, and the user enters the full sentence in the program. Sorry if I didn't explain that properly.

Comment: Holy c-.. uh, yes. Ingenious, I feel silly for not realizing that was possible. Thanks for correctly interpreting my question and guessing the right answer for me.

Comment: Please be very aware of sql injection though. You should make sure to parse the sentence the user typed so they do not put in any unwanted sql keywords.

Comment: For example makes sure to escape any ' characters...